# Linux USB : Request / Response over control endpoint?

Tags: c, linux, usb, linux-device-driver

I'm trying to develop a kernel driver for a card reader.  I have zero experience developing for the linux kernel and have never written a driver; it's also been a good 15 years since I've written any C code.

Using the many resources on the internet and the kernel source code I've cobbled together a driver.  Specifically I am now struggling with request / response over the control endpoint with the device.  My understanding is the control endpoint has functionality defined in the USB spec and a little wiggle room for vendors to support device specific functionality over this endpoint.  I can find a million references to "vendors implement proprietary features over the control endpoint" but for the life of me I can't find a simple example of how to set this up in my driver code.

Using usbpcap / wireshark and also USBLyzer I can monitor this device with the Windows demo software it came with.  In the USB traffic I monitored on Windows a control out (host to device) goes out and then the device responds with many control in packets.

This is the control out request info:
bmRequestType 21h
bRequest 09h
wValue 0300h
wIndex 0000h
wLength 0008h

The data itself is the hex string:
60 00 01 39 58 03 5f 00

I build and submit the same (I think) request in my driver code and usb_submit_urb() gives a return value of 0.  But I have no idea how to go about receiving the responses.

Here is the relevant code:

```
/* in header file */
struct usb_idtech {
    struct usb_device           *udev;
    struct usb_interface        *interface;

    unsigned char               minor;

    char                        *ctrl_buffer;
    struct urb                  *ctrl_urb;
    struct usb_ctrlrequest      *ctrl_req;

    int                         type;
};

/* in my probe callback */
dev->ctrl_req->bRequestType = IDTECH_CTRL_REQUEST_TYPE;
dev->ctrl_req->bRequest = IDTECH_CTRL_REQUEST;
dev->ctrl_req->wValue = IDTECH_CTRL_VALUE;
dev->ctrl_req->wIndex = IDTECH_CTRL_INDEX;
dev->ctrl_req->wLength = IDTECH_CTRL_BUFFER_SIZE;

usb_fill_control_urb( 
    dev->ctrl_urb,
    dev->udev,
    usb_sndctrlpipe( dev->udev, 0 ),
    (unsigned char *)dev->ctrl_req,
    dev->ctrl_buffer,
    IDTECH_CTRL_BUFFER_SIZE,
    idtech_ctrl_callback,
    dev
);

printk( KERN_INFO "submitting control urb" );
memcpy( dev->ctrl_buffer, "\x60\x00\x01\x39\x58\x03\xd2\x00", IDTECH_CTRL_BUFFER_SIZE );
printk( KERN_INFO "ctrl_buffer: %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x", 
    (unsigned char)dev->ctrl_buffer[ 0 ],
    (unsigned char)dev->ctrl_buffer[ 1 ],
    (unsigned char)dev->ctrl_buffer[ 2 ],
    (unsigned char)dev->ctrl_buffer[ 3 ],
    (unsigned char)dev->ctrl_buffer[ 4 ],
    (unsigned char)dev->ctrl_buffer[ 5 ],
    (unsigned char)dev->ctrl_buffer[ 6 ],
    (unsigned char)dev->ctrl_buffer[ 7 ]
);
result = usb_submit_urb( dev->ctrl_urb, GFP_KERNEL );
printk( KERN_INFO "control urb submitted %d", result );
```

This is the relevant dmesg data:

```
[13253.304464] idtech attached at idtech0
[13253.304479] submitting control urb
[13253.304498] ctrl_buffer: 60 00 01 39 58 03 d2 00
[13253.304574] control urb submitted 0
[13253.304907] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbidtech
[13253.305887] inside idtech_ctrl_callback
```

This is the output from usbmon:

```
f51a4980 2557517293 S Co:2:003:0 s 21 09 0300 0000 0008 8 = 60000139 5803d200
f51a4980 2557518637 C Co:2:003:0 0 8 >
```

Does what I'm doing so far appear correct?  And how do I get the response?  Why does usbmon output not show the device communicating back?

Thanks!

Comment: I'd recommend first writing an userspace application in C (perhaps using [libusb-1.0](http://www.libusb.org/)), to make sure you can control the device. You do not want to worry about both communications and kernel interfaces at the same time; too much to take at once. After the application works, start working on the kernel. Existing [USB storage](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/drivers/usb/storage) and [other USB](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/drivers/usb/misc) driver sources should help.